# FIFA 16 - History of transfer fees?

Tags: fifa-16

On carreer mode as a manager, is there a way to check how much I paid for a certain player?

I would like to keep track of that to know how much money I'm making with buying and selling players, but I can only check sth like `recently arrived from Foo for $ 1,000,000`

Comment: i have seen the transfer history menu on manager mode has all the transfers and the price. but that window refreshes with each transfer window. there is no player transfer history on record to see where the player was before